# Glossy buttons in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, graphics

Any ideas how to create a button class that looks something like this:

[image: Glossy Button]

Taken from [this tutorial page](http://iris-design.info/photoshop/web-20-style-buttons/). I'm struggling to figure out what combination of filters I need to use to achieve the glossy effect.

The rounded corners and bevel/glow effect are simple enough. But how can I add a gloss gradient over only the top half of the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/) has a [Button Loader](http://www.degrafa.org/source/ButtonLoader/ButtonLoader.html) thing that does this exactly.

Open source too.

Answer (score 1):

Use this App --> http://jirox.net/AsButtonGen/